# What should be flume.conf parametres for save tweets to single FlumeData file per hour?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, flume, tweetstream, flume-twitter

We are saving tweets in a directory order like /user/flume/2016/06/28/13/FlumeData... .But each hour it creates more than 100 FlumeData file.I have changed `TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 52428800 (50 mb)` same thing happened again.After that I tried with changing rollcount parametre too but didnt work.How can i set parametres to get one FlumeData file per hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with setting rollInterval=3600 rollcount=0 and batchSize=100 flume.conf parametres as @vkgade suggest

Answer (score 0):

What about `rollInterval`? Did you set it zero. If it is, then the issue might be something else. If the `rollInterval` is set to some value, it will kind of override the `rollSize` and `rollCount` values. The file rotation might happen before the file size reaches the `rollSize` value. Also, check the HDFS block size you set. If it is set to, too small value even that might cause the file rolling.

Try this -

```
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://hpc01:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 100


    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0

    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 0

    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 3600
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 1000

    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Comment: rollInterval was unsetted but i think default value is zero already and our hdfs block size is 128mb.

Comment: Can you post the flume configuration file here? Initially even I had the same problem. I could not create 1 file per hour due to memory errors (due to channel capacities are not working properly) but I brought it down to 4 to 5 files per hour. Each file sizes up to 8MB. I put the channel capacity as 1000 and transaction capacity to 100. Then put the file size to 8000000 and rest roll parameters to zero. Importantly, the batch size (I put it at 100) notch it up according to the channel capacity.   Try that and let me know how are your results.

Comment: You have put the roll count to 10, change it to zero. The roll count is causing those hundreds of files. Increase the batch size to 100 or more. Put the roll interval as 1 hour  (3600 seconds) and see what happens.

Comment: Try the configuration I added in my answer.

Comment: It did not work you mean - it is still creating large number of small files?

Comment: Hey.. Your `rollInterval` spelling is wrong in the configuration file.

Comment: i thinks it is correct.I copy-paste [https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html] from here.

Comment: but i am trying again from all beginning.

Comment: i tried with 10 roll intervall (just for trying) i think it is working now i will wait 1 hour thanks for quick reply.

Comment: If the `rollInterval=10`, it will create a new file every 10 seconds. I believe that is not what we want.

Comment: sure i set this value for trying correctness and set back again 3600 ,it is working now one file per hour.

Comment: good.. is it the same configuration as given in my answer (I updated it). If yes accept my answer.

Comment: Before you accept my solution correct, try running the configuration for at least 5 hours (without any errors). If it did throw some errors, post those errors back here.

Answer (score 0):

```
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://hpc01:8020/user/flume/tweets/%Y/%m/%d/%H
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 1


TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 10

TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 10000

TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 1000
```

Comment: Hey check here in your answer, the `rollInterval` is written as `rollIntInterval`. That's incorrect.